# NSNumber possible memory leak

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, nsnumber

Create an ARC new project and inject this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", num);
}

NSLog(@"over");
```

Application's memory will increase.
Also, at the end of the for loop, memory will not decrease.

However, if you replace in that same for loop:

```
NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
```

by

```
NSNumber* num = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];
```

Then memory will remain stable.

Is this an expected behaviour?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so let's put didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on side for the moment.
You can still put in viewDidLoad and remove a zero in order to reach the end of for loop quicker
Memory of the app will grow till ~11 MB. When the for loop ends, the memory will NOT decrease. It remains at ~11 MB.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
        NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", num);
    }

    NSLog(@"over");
}
```

If you go with :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
            NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
            NSLog(@"%@", num);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"over");
}
```

Surprise! Surprise!
You'll have the exact same behaviour. You'll reach ~11 MB and memory will NOT decrease. However, putting the @autorelease inside the loop will work... But here, I'm not trying to make things work but understand why memory is not drained at the end of the for loop.

So, question is still open.

Comment: Interesting.. Waiting for specialists opinions on this one..

Comment: What if you put `@autoreleasepool { ... }` around the `for` statement?

Comment: Have you tried with other Foundation classes ? What about an init with another type (initWithBool: for example) ?

Comment: How do you measure amount of memory actually used?

Comment: You have yet to explain *how* you are measuring the memory usage of your app.

Comment: Does this happen only with NSNumber? Have you tried other classes?

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. When you allocate the `NSNumber` with alloc/init, ARC will free it as soon as it is no longer needed.

When you allocate it with a convenience method like `numberWithInt:` what you will obtain is an object allocated in an autorelease pool. Until the autorelease pool is drained, you memory will not be freed. However, you can create an autorelease pool for your loop like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) @autoreleasepool {
    NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", num);
}

NSLog(@"over");
```

This should free the number after each look iteration.

You can get further details here: 
[Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Comment: This can't be the reason. The main thread already has an autorelease pool, which is drained on every runloop hop. Those numbers will be freed a moment after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` exits.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, it will.

Comment: Indeed.  Unusual syntax, though.

Comment: @hamstergene they are not freed as the method exits, I tried it. This is because the main thread loop is not active until the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method returns. See http://goo.gl/Nz9hve

Comment: That is unusual, if true, and I would have expected the lack of a (system-provided) autoreleasepool to be both documented in the `UIApplicationDelegate` reference and provided as part of the Xcode app templates.  Just because the event loop doesn't start until later, doesn't mean the autoreleasepool (in `main.m`) is not active.

Comment: @Jorge That's what I said, after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` returns, the runloop will continue, and implicitly provided autorelease pool will be drained, causing everything autoreleased to be released. This is primary use case of autoreleasing after all.